# Creating rule for update view sql error

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to create **UpdaeTable view**.

I have table `product, category, product_has_category`.

```
CREATE TABLE "category" (
"category_id" SERIAL NOT NULL,
"name" varchar(15) NOT NULL,
"description" varchar(150) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY("category_id")
);

CREATE TABLE "product" (
"product_id" SERIAL NOT NULL,
"name" varchar(20) NOT NULL,
"price" int4 NOT NULL,
"description" varchar(200),
"country_of_origin" varchar(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY("product_id")
);


CREATE TABLE "product_has_category" (
"NMID" SERIAL NOT NULL,
"product_id" int4 NOT NULL,
"category_id" int4 NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE "product_has_category" 
ADD CONSTRAINT "Ref_Product_has_Category_to_Product" FOREIGN KEY ("Product_product_id")
REFERENCES "Product"("product_id")
MATCH SIMPLE
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE
NOT DEFERRABLE;
```

And here is view that selects products, its price and categories:

```
CREATE VIEW products_with_categories AS
SELECT product.name AS product_name, product.price, category.name AS     category
FROM product, category, product_has_category
WHERE product_has_category.product_id = product.product_id AND
product_has_category.category_id = category.category_id
ORDER BY product_name;
```

I want view to be updatable and created the rule:

```
CREATE RULE prod_cat_upd AS ON UPDATE TO products_with_categories 
DO INSTEAD 
UPDATE product 
   SET product.name=NEW.product.name 
WHERE product.name=OLD.product.name
```

And I got the following error:

> invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "product"
>       Hint: There is an entry for table "product", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.

I can not understand what does this error means and how to solve this problem.

Comment: Go back to your old questions, and accept answers if helps you. Because right now from 11 Questions you asked, only one you accepted. One does not have answer(as duplicate), other 9 question have answer but you don't eithr accept nor upvote them, so Try to accept answers, if that helps you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This syntax to CREATE RULE, [Refer](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/rules-update.html) for more documentation

```
CREATE RULE prod_cat_upd AS ON UPDATE TO products_with_categories 
DO INSTEAD 
UPDATE product 
       SET name=NEW.name
WHERE name=OLD.name
```

I created Two SQL Fiddle with the Sample Table

1) <kbd>[Sample SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/eb1f0)</kbd> with solution, I provide :- Working fine

```
    CREATE TABLE shoelace_data (
    sl_name    text,          -- primary key
    sl_avail   integer,       -- available number of pairs
    sl_color   text,          -- shoelace color
    sl_len     real,          -- shoelace length
    sl_unit    text           -- length unit
);

CREATE TABLE unit (
    un_name    text,          -- primary key
    un_fact    real           -- factor to transform to cm
);

CREATE VIEW shoelace AS
    SELECT s.sl_name,
           s.sl_avail,
           s.sl_color,
           s.sl_len,
           s.sl_unit,
           s.sl_len * u.un_fact AS sl_len_cm
      FROM shoelace_data s, unit u
     WHERE s.sl_unit = u.un_name;

CREATE RULE shoelace_upd AS ON UPDATE TO shoelace
    DO INSTEAD
    UPDATE shoelace_data
       SET sl_name = NEW.sl_name,
           sl_avail = NEW.sl_avail,
           sl_color = NEW.sl_color,
           sl_len = NEW.sl_len,
           sl_unit = NEW.sl_unit
     WHERE sl_name = OLD.sl_name;
```

2) The Code you have for CREATE RULE :- Failed and have the same error what you get

**NOT Working**

```
CREATE RULE shoelace_upd AS ON UPDATE TO shoelace
    DO INSTEAD
    UPDATE shoelace_data
       SET shoelace_data.sl_name = NEW.shoelace_data.sl_name,
           shoelace_data.sl_avail = NEW.shoelace_data.sl_avail,
           shoelace_data.sl_color = NEW.shoelace_data.sl_color,
           shoelace_data.sl_len = NEW.shoelace_data.sl_len,
           shoelace_data.sl_unit = NEW.shoelace_data.sl_unit
     WHERE shoelace_data.sl_name = OLD.shoelace_data.sl_name;
```

**EDIT:-**
 You are getting this error:-

> ERROR: column new.name does not exist

Because your view does not have 'name' as field, your view only have these three fields :- `product_name, price and category` so use these fields only

```
CREATE RULE prod_cat_upd AS ON UPDATE TO products_with_categories 
DO INSTEAD 
UPDATE product 
       SET name=NEW.product_name
WHERE name=OLD.product_name
```

Comment: The only difference I see between your code and OP's is the formatting. What am I missing?

Comment: see, little different.... OP uses table name with column, and thats not required as per documentation, and that OP missing

Comment: @Piyush I tried right syntax, but got the error: ERROR: column new.name does not exist

Comment: @user2950602:- can you post your new query where you get error?

Comment: @Piyush CREATE RULE prod_cat_upd AS ON UPDATE TO products_with_categories 
DO INSTEAD 
UPDATE product 
   SET name=NEW.name 
WHERE name=OLD.name

Comment: @user2950602:- this error because your view does not have 'name' as field, your view only have these three fields :- product_name, price and category so use these fields only. SEE EDIT in Answer